# How would i retrieve the cropped image using get image by using toolkit?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Graphics/src/name2.jpg"));         

ImageFilter filter = new CropImageFilter(0, 0, 250, 250);
    ImageProducer producer = new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(), filter);

Image resultImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
    producer);
ImageIO.write(resultImage, "jpg", 
    new File("C:/Graphics/src/name7.jpg"));  //not allowing me
```

//this is the line displays error as:

```
The method write(RenderedImage, String, File) in the type ImageIO is not 
    applicable for the arguments (Image, String, File)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(x,y,,w,h)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for the sub-image.

To gain a `BufferedImage`, use [`ImageIO.read(File/InputStream/URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29).

---

```
The method write(RenderedImage, String, File) in the type ImageIO is not 
    applicable for the arguments (Image, String, File)
```

The `image` is apparently declared as an `Image`, change it to:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Graphics/src/name2.jpg"));
```

Comment: This is the code and i want to write the image to the file, but its not allowing me.

Comment: See the update to my answer.  (And please delete your 1st & 2nd comment to me - they are noise now.)

Comment: I have declared BufferedImage image = null; before.